# Speedup of git push custom ref object

Tags: git, git-push

I would like to store a custom (very small, 500B max.) objects in a Git repository (e.g. see [Gerrit NoteDB](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/note-db.html) or [How to use native git as a key-value store](https://graphite.dev/blog/git-key-value)). So I do:

```bash
LOCK_OBJ_ID=$(echo ..some data... | git hash-object -w --stdin)
git update-ref refs/myrefs/somedata "$LOCK_OBJ_ID"
git push origin refs/myrefs/somedata
```

That works well, however, the push is slow (e.g. it takes about 2 seconds on GitHub). Is there any way how to speed up `git push` when simple a object is sent only? Maybe something to skip the common `git push` client - server conversation and do it in one request?

Comment: Is this issue specific to GitHub or does it happen with other git servers as well?

Comment: @dan1st GitHub is just an example. It's a general `git push` behaviour. Which is good for normal work. I just need to speed it up for this special case.

Comment: Does it work better if you can compress/"pack" the objects before pushing? How big are your objects? See also https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles

Comment: @dan1st Very small object, 500B max. I've tried it with `GIT_TRACE=true` and packing is not a problem.

Comment: When you push to a repository, the parties (your local Git and the remote Git) negotiate which objects to transfer. To do so, they exchange basically all the refs (tags, branches) they have. This may be way more data than the tiny object that you attempt to push and may take the time that you observe.

Comment: @jt6 Yes, that's what I've mentioned in the question: *skip the common `git push` client - server conversation*. So, the sole question is about if there's is a way, how to push a tiny object without that?

Comment: Is there a difference in the time it takes whether you are using SSH or HTTPs for pushing?

Comment: @dan1st SSH is just about 0.2 sec slower on GitHub. It's not a significant difference.